# Why does my git diff commit commit doesn't work

Tags: git, diff, commit

I have the following commits:

```
$ git log --oneline
67a48c4 (HEAD -> main) Add a line in toto.py
62430ad Add file tata
0447f39 Add file toto
```

But when I try to diff two of those commits I get an error:

```
$ git diff 62430ad7f5bbd2437969b4d9086f729c3a224c5a 0447f395630849f2c40f6c11939f1a4c4c811f73
```

> fatal: ambiguous argument '62430ad7f5bbd2437969b4d9086f729c3a224c5a': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] -- [...]

What is the cause here?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's my first time in stack so i'm looking forward to improving the way i sask questions.
I still have the same error message. To be more specific i'll write down the whole message:

fatal: ambiguous argument '62430ad7f5bbd2437969b4d9086f729c3a224c5a': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

I'm executing `git diff` in the same folder as `git log`

Comment: `git version 2.37.3.windows.1 `


Same issue with `git 62430ad 0447f39`

Comment: did you try with `..` between instead of space?

Comment: Yes, still the same

Comment: @Souf can you try `git diff 0447f39 62430ad`? Perhaps you have a typo in the full commit hashes. Are you in the correct directory? No submodules or nested repositories? Do you execute `git diff` in the same directory as `git log`? What does `git rev-parse --git-dir` output?

Comment: hi,
it's finally working. the issue was in the way i copied the IDs. I was using the short cut Ctrl + Shift + C but i don't know why eventhough i managed to copy the exact line something wrong was happening. Now i use the mouse or the Shift + Insert keys dans it works juste fine.
Thank you everyone !

Comment: Questuon should be closed, it was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's finally working. the issue was in the way i copied the IDs. I was using the short cut Ctrl + Shift + C but i don't know why eventhough i managed to copy the exact line something wrong was happening. Now i use the mouse or the Shift + Insert keys dans it works juste fine. Thank you everyone !